# WKT Conversion: Object: Error in executing tool

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, convert, well-known-text

I have a script below where I am trying to convert a CSV of a WKT polygons that I would like to export out into a shapefile and keep getting the following error on line 21 with: `arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(output_folder,output_shapefile_name + ".shp", "POLYGON", spatial_reference)`

The error I am receiving is:

> Object: Error in executing tool

I have checked the spatial reference, am at a loss at what might be causing this issue. Could it be a folder permissions issue with where the files are located?

```py
import arcpy
import csv
import os

# Set the input CSV file path containing WKT polygons
input_csv_file = r"Z:\ArcGIS\Name\File.csv"

# Set the output folder path for the shapefile
output_folder = r"Z:\ArcGIS\Name\Nationwide"

# Set the output shapefile name (without extension)
output_shapefile_name = "NationGh6"

# Create a spatial reference object for WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Create the output shapefile path
output_shapefile = os.path.join(output_folder, output_shapefile_name + ".shp")

# Create the output shapefile with the specified fields and spatial reference
arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(output_folder,output_shapefile_name + ".shp", "POLYGON", spatial_reference)

# Add a field to store the WKT representation
arcpy.management.AddField(output_shapefile, "GH6Polygon", "TEXT")

# Open the input CSV file and create an insert cursor for the shapefile
with open(input_csv_file, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    # Create an insert cursor for the shapefile
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_shapefile, ["SHAPE@","GH6Polygon"]) as insert_cursor:
        for row in csv_reader:
            # Get the WKT polygon from the CSV row
            wkt_polygon = row["GH6Polygon"]

            # Create a Geometry object from the WKT with the specified spatial reference
            geom = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt_polygon, spatial_reference)

            # Create a polygon feature for polygons
            if geom.type == 'polygon':
                polygon = arcpy.Polygon(geom, spatial_reference)
                insert_cursor.insertRow([polygon, wkt_polygon])

print(f"Conversion from CSV to shapefile '{output_shapefile}' complete.")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [tool reference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm) for Create Feature Class you can see that the:

- first parameter is: path,
- second: name,
- third: type and
- fourth: template

So you are passing spatial_reference as the template with:
`arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(output_folder,output_shapefile_name + ".shp", "POLYGON", spatial_reference)`

Specify the parameter names to fix it *and* make the code more readable:

`arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(out_path=output_folder, out_name=output_shapefile_name+".shp", geometry_type="polygon", spatial_reference=spatial_reference)`